# MySQL query help needed to get clients who haven't bought anything in more than 180 days!

Tags: mysql

I have a table Orders which stores the info about orders(including OrdersName,OrdersSurname,OrdersEmail,OrdersPhone) which is the info I need to get.

It contains a field OrdersFinishedTime which is a DateTime field which stores the data when the order was finished.

What I need to do is select OrdersName,OrdersSurname,OrdersEmail,OrdersPhone from the Orders table for users who haven't bought anything in more than 180 days.

That is - I need to find unique users who's LAST UNIQUE purchase was more than 180 days ago.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I know how to find all the records order than 180 days, but I need records which are 180 days older and there are no more orders(for that particular user) after that date!

**EDIT2:
you probably are not reading the question through. I need to find unique users who haven't purchased anything in more than 180 days. I don't need orders older than 180 days, I need the user info which is stored in the orders.**

my current SQL query is like this:

SELECT DISTINCT O.`OrdersEmail`,O.`OrdersName`,O.`OrdersSurname`,O.`OrdersPhone`,O.`OrdersFinishedTime`
FROM (SELECT `OrdersPhone`, MAX(`OrdersFinishedTime`) AS `OrdersFinishedTime` FROM `Orders`
WHERE YEAR(`OrdersFinishedTime`) >= 2010 GROUP BY `OrdersPhone` HAVING DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(`OrdersFinishedTime`)) >= 180) AS LastOrders
INNER JOIN `Orders` AS O USING(`OrdersPhone`,`OrdersFinishedTime`) ORDER BY `OrdersFinishedTime` DESC

Comment: What's your problem ? Join or Datetime functions ?

Comment: The Query returns information about clients which have orders with purchases later on

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrdersName,OrdersSurname,OrdersEmail,OrdersPhone from Orders
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(OrdersFinishedTime) > 180
ORDER BY OrdersFinishedTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Last order which is more than 180 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT `OrdersName`, `OrdersSurname`, `OrdersEmail`, `OrdersPhone` FROM `Orders ` WHERE `OrdersFinishedTime` < SUBDATE(NOW(), 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely something like the following would do the trick.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrdersName,OrdersSurname,OrdersEmail,OrdersPhone FROM Orders
   WHERE OrdersID IN 
       (SELECT OrdersID FROM Orders 
        WHERE OrdersFinishedTime < (NOW() - INTERVAL 180 DAY))
```

Comment: this returns all the orders with the finished date more than 180 days ago... What I need is only the LAST order which is more than 180 days ago

Comment: now revised to only pull out the last customer based on order date

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrdersFinishedTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)